# How to use linux variables in .env of vue.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, vue.js

When I used .env in *.js file, I could use BANK=$BANK_OPTION
that meant of

```
BANK=A_BANK
```

or

```
BANK=B_BANK
```

but when i put argument as A_BANK or B_BANK later like

```
--bank A_BANK
```

in the shell script of

```
for var in $@
do
  if [ ${var} = "--porta" ];then
   exist=1
   continue
  elif [ ${var} = "--portb" ];then
   exist=2
   continue
  elif [ ${var} = "--portc" ];then
   exist=3
   continue
  elif [ ${var} = "--bank" ];then
   exist=4
  continue
  fi
  if [ ${exist} == 1 ];then
   PORT_A=${var}
   continue;
  elif [ ${exist} == 2 ];then
   PORT_B=${var}
   continue;
  elif [ ${exist} == 3 ];then
   PORT_C=${var}
   continue;
  elif [ ${exist} == 4 ];then
   BANK_OPTION=${var}
  continue;
  fi
done
```

that A_BANK is written well into the nodejs variables as BANK_OPTION=A_BANK or BANK_OPTION=B_BANK

but in the VUE.js it was written just as $BANK_OPTION, not A_BANK or B_BANK

How can we control this to be written as A_BANK or B_BANK in VUE.js?

Comment: Vue is a front-end framework. It runs in a browser. It has no direct access to the `.env` file that's stored on your server (thankfully). If it did, anybody could freely read any secret or key that's stored in this file, so... it's a good thing I guess :)

Comment: Take a look here at vue documentation for env variables https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html But as @JeremyThille said, be aware of not mixing up backend and frontend env variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nodejs that can refer to environment variable settings. Node runs on your server.

vue.js code runs on your browser. Your server environment variables aren't available in that context. In most cases your web server delivers your vue.js  code to your server as a static file.

To make an environment or other server variable available to browser javascript you must include it in a page you construct with a template.

It's hard to be more specific without knowing a bit more about your app.

Comment: If what will I show you about the app then you can answer more specific? Now I gave up making dynamic variable in .env and made it static and change the value with sed.